# SQL Server Partitioning. creating new partition for next year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, partitioning

I have a partition scheme setup that is currently split by year. I am trying to create a new partition for next year:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Log

    NEXT USED Year7FileGroup;

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfYearlyPartition_Log()

    SPLIT RANGE('20190101');
```

This however is running for many hours and not completing. Does anyone know why this could be occurring as there doesn't seem to be any 2019 data yet?

The last partition is from 2016-01-01 until today.

I ran the queries at the bottom of this post, which gave the following the results:

```
 CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pfYearlyPartition](datetime) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES('2012-01-01T00:00:00','2013-01-01T00:00:00','2014-01-01T00:00:00','2015-01-01T00:00:00','2016-01-01T00:00:00');

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table1] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table2] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table3] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table4] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table5] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table6] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table7] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table8] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table9] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table10] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table11] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table12] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table13] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table14] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table15] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table16] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table17] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table18] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table19] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table20] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table21] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table22] AS PARTTITION [pfYearlyPartition] TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup],[YEAR11FileGroup]);
```

[image]

```
SELECT
  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(pstats.object_id) AS SchemaName
  ,OBJECT_NAME(pstats.object_id) AS TableName
  ,ps.name AS PartitionSchemeName
  ,ds.name AS PartitionFilegroupName
  ,pf.name AS PartitionFunctionName
  ,CASE pf.boundary_value_on_right WHEN 0 THEN 'Range Left' ELSE 'Range Right' END AS PartitionFunctionRange
  ,CASE pf.boundary_value_on_right WHEN 0 THEN 'Upper Boundary' ELSE 'Lower Boundary' END AS PartitionBoundary
  ,prv.value AS PartitionBoundaryValue
  ,c.name AS PartitionKey
  ,CASE 
    WHEN pf.boundary_value_on_right = 0 
    THEN c.name + ' > ' + CAST(ISNULL(LAG(prv.value) OVER(PARTITION BY pstats.object_id ORDER BY pstats.object_id, pstats.partition_number), 'Infinity') AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' and ' + c.name + ' <= ' + CAST(ISNULL(prv.value, 'Infinity') AS VARCHAR(100)) 
    ELSE c.name + ' >= ' + CAST(ISNULL(prv.value, 'Infinity') AS VARCHAR(100))  + ' and ' + c.name + ' < ' + CAST(ISNULL(LEAD(prv.value) OVER(PARTITION BY pstats.object_id ORDER BY pstats.object_id, pstats.partition_number), 'Infinity') AS VARCHAR(100))
  END AS PartitionRange
  ,pstats.partition_number AS PartitionNumber
  ,pstats.row_count AS PartitionRowCount
  ,p.data_compression_desc AS DataCompression
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS pstats
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON pstats.partition_id = p.partition_id
INNER JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces AS dds ON pstats.partition_number = dds.destination_id
INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS ds ON dds.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes AS ps ON dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.partition_functions AS pf ON ps.function_id = pf.function_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON pstats.object_id = i.object_id AND pstats.index_id = i.index_id AND dds.partition_scheme_id = i.data_space_id AND i.type <= 1 /* Heap or Clustered Index */
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic ON i.index_id = ic.index_id AND i.object_id = ic.object_id AND ic.partition_ordinal > 0
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON pstats.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values AS prv ON pf.function_id = prv.function_id AND pstats.partition_number = (CASE pf.boundary_value_on_right WHEN 0 THEN prv.boundary_id ELSE (prv.boundary_id+1) END)
ORDER BY TableName, PartitionNumber;

SELECT
      N'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION ' 
    + QUOTENAME(pf.name)
    + N'(' + t.name  + N')'
    + N' AS RANGE ' 
    + CASE WHEN pf.boundary_value_on_right = 1 THEN N'RIGHT' ELSE N'LEFT' END
    + ' FOR VALUES('
    +
    (SELECT
        STUFF((SELECT
            N','
            + CASE
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') IN(N'char', N'varchar') 
                    THEN QUOTENAME(CAST(r.value AS nvarchar(4000)), '''')
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') IN(N'nchar', N'nvarchar') 
                    THEN N'N' + QUOTENAME(CAST(r.value AS nvarchar(4000)), '''')
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') = N'date' 
                    THEN QUOTENAME(FORMAT(CAST(r.value AS date), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'''')
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') = N'datetime' 
                    THEN QUOTENAME(FORMAT(CAST(r.value AS datetime), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'),'''')
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') IN(N'datetime', N'smalldatetime') 
                    THEN QUOTENAME(FORMAT(CAST(r.value AS datetime), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff'),'''')
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') = N'datetime2' 
                    THEN QUOTENAME(FORMAT(CAST(r.value AS datetime2), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff'),'''')
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') = N'datetimeoffset' 
                    THEN QUOTENAME(FORMAT(CAST(r.value AS datetimeoffset), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff K'),'''')
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') = N'time' 
                    THEN QUOTENAME(FORMAT(CAST(r.value AS time), 'hh\:mm\:ss\.fffffff'),'''') --'HH\:mm\:ss\.fffffff'
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') = N'uniqueidentifier' 
                    THEN QUOTENAME(CAST(r.value AS nvarchar(4000)), '''')
                  WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(r.value, 'BaseType') IN (N'binary', N'varbinary') 
                    THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), r.value, 1)
                  ELSE CAST(r.value AS nvarchar(4000))
              END
    FROM sys.partition_range_values AS r
    WHERE pf.[function_id] = r.[function_id]
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'')
    )
    + N');'
FROM sys.partition_functions pf
JOIN sys.partition_parameters AS pp ON
    pp.function_id = pf.function_id
JOIN sys.types AS t ON
    t.system_type_id = pp.system_type_id
    AND t.user_type_id = pp.user_type_id

SELECT
      N'CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ' + QUOTENAME(ps.name)
    + N' AS PARTTITION ' + QUOTENAME(pf.name)
    + N' TO ('
    +
    (SELECT
        STUFF((SELECT
            N',' + QUOTENAME(fg.name)
    FROM sys.data_spaces ds
    JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces AS dds ON dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id
    JOIN sys.filegroups AS fg ON fg.data_space_id = dds.data_space_id
    WHERE ps.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id
    ORDER BY dds.destination_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'')
    )
    + N');'
FROM sys.partition_schemes AS ps
JOIN sys.partition_functions AS pf ON pf.function_id = ps.function_id
```

Comment: Are you using type varchar instead of date(time) for that column? I guess that is not very efficient?

Comment: No it's a datetime field

Comment: Use `sp_whoisactive` to see what is going on

Comment: I'm going to be riding the same boat soon. Mines is based on per year. I also have seperate file group for each year. =/ I plan on doing this off hours. Partition is based on date column.

Comment: @junketsu, the generalized script in my answer will work with `date` too. If yours is a `RANGE RIGHT` function, you can probably get away with just adding a new boundary to the end of the function by altering the scheme and function as Philip attempted originally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this could be occurring as there doesn't seem to
>   be any 2019 data yet?

When you split a non-empty partition, the existing partition is split into 2 separate ones and rows are moved into the newly-created partition to accommodate the new boundaries. This is a very expensive operation, requiring about 4 times the logging of normal DML operations. Splitting non-empty partitions should be avoided, especially with a large table like you apparently have.

To avoid such data movement, you can use a staging table and temporary partition function/scheme for the partition maintenance. That would allow you to SWITCH the partition to be split into the staging table, use `CREATE INDEX...WITH (DROP EXISTING=ON)` to create new partitions, and finally `SWITCH` the partitions back into the main table.

If you need help with a script to do this, add the CREATE DDL for your existing partition function and scheme to your question. Details like `RANGE LEFT` or `RIGHT` are important. I'm guessing you have a `RANGE LEFT` function, which would move all rows greater than '2016-01-01' and less than or equal to '2019-01-01' into a newly created partition.

**EDIT**

I see now that you have dozens of tables all partitioned using the same underlying function. There looks to be an error in the generated partition scheme script as it contains an extra filegroup, which seems to be the `NEXT USED` filegroup even though it's not actually used. I assume the Year11FileGroup is not actually used.

Below is an example script for 2 tables you can extend as needed. Because the schemes share the same function, you'll need to perform each step against all tables at the same time because splitting the function will affect all schemes along with tables and indexes partitioned using those schemes. I also added a boundary for the year 2020 future boundary (on YearFileGroup7) so that you can avoid this problem going forward by proactively creating the year 2021 partition before the end of the 2019 calendar year by setting the `NEXT USED` filegroup for each scheme and splitting the function as you attempted originally.

```
--create temp function like original
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pfYearlyPartition_temp](datetime) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES('2012-01-01T00:00:00','2013-01-01T00:00:00','2014-01-01T00:00:00','2015-01-01T00:00:00','2016-01-01T00:00:00');

--create temp scheme like original for each scheme
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table1_temp] AS PARTITION pfYearlyPartition_temp TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup]);
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psYearlyPartition_Table2_temp] AS PARTITION pfYearlyPartition_temp TO ([YEAR1FileGroup],[YEAR2FileGroup],[YEAR3FileGroup],[YEAR4FileGroup],[YEAR5FileGroup],[YEAR6FileGroup]);

--for each table, create temporary staging table and indexes like original partitioned using temp scheme
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1_temp(
      Col1 datetime
    , Col2 int
    , Col3 char(1000) 
) ON psYearlyPartition_Table1_temp(col1);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.Table1_temp(Col2, Col1)  ON psYearlyPartition_Table1_temp(Col1);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.Table1_temp(Col2) ON psYearlyPartition_Table1_temp(Col1);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2_temp(
      Col1 datetime
    , Col2 int
    , Col3 char(1000) 
) ON psYearlyPartition_Table2_temp(col1);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.Table2_temp(Col2, Col1)  ON psYearlyPartition_Table2_temp(Col1);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.Table2_temp(Col2) ON psYearlyPartition_Table2_temp(Col1);
GO

--for each table, switch the partition containing the new boundary (the partition to be split) into temp table
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2019-01-01T00:00:00')
    TO dbo.Table1_temp PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_temp('2019-01-01T00:00:00');
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2019-01-01T00:00:00')
    TO dbo.Table2_temp PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition_temp('2019-01-01T00:00:00');
GO

--for each original scheme, set NEXT USED filegrroup and split original function to create new boundaries
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Table1 NEXT USED [Year6FileGroup];
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Table2 NEXT USED [Year6FileGroup];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfYearlyPartition() SPLIT RANGE('2019-01-01T00:00:00');
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Table1 NEXT USED [Year7FileGroup];
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Table2 NEXT USED [Year7FileGroup];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfYearlyPartition() SPLIT RANGE('2020-01-01T00:00:00');
GO

--for each table, repartition temp table and indexes using the original scheme which now contains the new boundaries
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.Table1_temp(Col2, Col1) WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON) ON psYearlyPartition_Table1(Col1) ;
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.Table1_temp(Col2) WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON) ON psYearlyPartition_Table1(Col1);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.Table2_temp(Col2, Col1) WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON) ON psYearlyPartition_Table2(Col1) ;
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.Table2_temp(Col2) WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON) ON psYearlyPartition_Table2(Col1);
GO

--for each table, switch temp table partitions back into main table
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1_temp
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2019-01-01T00:00:00')
    TO dbo.Table1 PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2019-01-01T00:00:00');
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2_temp
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2019-01-01T00:00:00')
    TO dbo.Table2 PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2019-01-01T00:00:00');
--this partition should be empty but just in case...
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1_temp
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2020-01-01T00:00:00')
    TO dbo.Table1 PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2020-01-01T00:00:00');
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2_temp
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2020-01-01T00:00:00')
    TO dbo.Table2 PARTITION $PARTITION.pfYearlyPartition('2020-01-01T00:00:00');
GO
--drop temp tables, schemes, and function
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1_temp;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table2_temp;
DROP PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Table1_temp;
DROP PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Table2_temp;
DROP PARTITION FUNCTION pfYearlyPartition_temp;
GO
```

Below is the result after running this script against test tables with 1M rows per year. Note that the last partition of a RANGE LEFT function is a permanent partition that will always be part of underlying schemes so the YEAR6FileGroup will always be used regardless of whether it contains data.

I recommend one use a `RANGE RIGHT` function for incremental temporal values because it's more intuitive and would have avoided this problem. Also, be aware that with `RANGE LEFT`, rows that exactly match the boundary value will end up in the wrong partition (e.g. a row with '2016-01-01T00:00:00' will be in the same partition as the 2015 data), which is a consideration when the partitioning time includes a time component. I suggest you peruse this [table partitioning best practices article](https://www.dbdelta.com/table-partitioning-best-practices/) for more information.

```
+------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| SchemaName | TableName |   PartitionSchemeName    | PartitionFilegroupName | PartitionFunctionName | PartitionFunctionRange | PartitionBoundary | PartitionBoundaryValue  | PartitionKey |                       PartitionRange                       | PartitionNumber | PartitionRowCount | DataCompression |
+------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| dbo        | Table1    | psYearlyPartition_Table1 | YEAR1FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Infinity and Col1 <= Jan  1 2012 12:00AM            |               1 |                 0 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table1    | psYearlyPartition_Table1 | YEAR2FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2012 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2013 12:00AM |               2 |           1000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table1    | psYearlyPartition_Table1 | YEAR3FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2013 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2014 12:00AM |               3 |           1000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table1    | psYearlyPartition_Table1 | YEAR4FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2014 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2015 12:00AM |               4 |           1000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table1    | psYearlyPartition_Table1 | YEAR5FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2015 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2016 12:00AM |               5 |           1000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table1    | psYearlyPartition_Table1 | YEAR6FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2016 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2019 12:00AM |               6 |           3000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table1    | psYearlyPartition_Table1 | YEAR7FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2019 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2020 12:00AM |               7 |                 0 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table1    | psYearlyPartition_Table1 | YEAR6FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | NULL                    | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2020 12:00AM and Col1 <= Infinity            |               8 |                 0 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table2    | psYearlyPartition_Table2 | YEAR1FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Infinity and Col1 <= Jan  1 2012 12:00AM            |               1 |                 0 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table2    | psYearlyPartition_Table2 | YEAR2FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2012 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2013 12:00AM |               2 |           1000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table2    | psYearlyPartition_Table2 | YEAR3FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2013 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2014 12:00AM |               3 |           1000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table2    | psYearlyPartition_Table2 | YEAR4FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2014 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2015 12:00AM |               4 |           1000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table2    | psYearlyPartition_Table2 | YEAR5FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2015 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2016 12:00AM |               5 |           1000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table2    | psYearlyPartition_Table2 | YEAR6FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2016 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2019 12:00AM |               6 |           3000000 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table2    | psYearlyPartition_Table2 | YEAR7FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2019 12:00AM and Col1 <= Jan  1 2020 12:00AM |               7 |                 0 | NONE            |
| dbo        | Table2    | psYearlyPartition_Table2 | YEAR6FileGroup         | pfYearlyPartition     | Range Left             | Upper Boundary    | NULL                    | Col1         | Col1 > Jan  1 2020 12:00AM and Col1 <= Infinity            |               8 |                 0 | NONE            |
+------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I'd like to add that is a good idea to keep an empty partition at the end of the scheme. That way, when you go to split it, the data movement necessary is nothing.

Comment: @Philip, thanks for the DDL. I see now that you have dozens of tables all partitioned using the same underlying function. There looks to be an error in the partition scheme script as it contains an extra filegroup, which seems to be the `NEXT USED` filegroup even though it's not actually used. I don't have time to add an script to my answer right now but will follow up. I wouldn't have expected a lot of data movement with the `RANGE RIGHT` so I'm wondering if concurrent activity was blocking the operation. Did you check that during your original attempt?

Comment: Thanks Dan. What I've suddenly noticed after your above message is that the first script is saying RANGE RIGHT, but the other script is returning RIGHT LEFT if you check the screenshot.  Do you have another reliable query I can use to 100% confirm which it is?

Comment: @Philip, there was an error in the script that generates the `CREATE FUNCTION` DDL. I corrected the script in your question. Please rerun it to see if it now returns LEFT.

Comment: @DanGuzman - thanks Dan, have updated the results of the query. It is indeed LEFT.

Comment: @Philip, added to my answer. I should add that no data movement would have been needed with `RANGE RIGHT`, although it's still a best practices to `SPLIT` empty partitions.

Comment: Thank very much for that @DanGuzman - really appreciate it. I'll test it out and let you know. Would you see this taking many hours to complete, and requiring a lot of disk space? Or are these steps relatively seamless?

Comment: LOL Saw the partition F-up with my left range. Reading it in your article I knew I was in for a ride. I took care of my tables today. Most of business was out and I didnt want to leave it out post newyears. Did it for next 3 years and saved the script. TY again @DanGuzman